# How to add code to SharePoint 2010 master page

Tags: sharepoint-2010, master-pages, sharepoint-branding

I have created custom master page with custom elements included according to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg447066.aspx

I want to have a Suggestions form in header area where users can leave their comments/suggestions on what functionality they would like to have.

For example:

- User goes to company team site and notes that it would be great to have a clock on it
- User fills the Suggestions form and the suggestion is emailed to me
- Now I decide will I implement/develop it or not

I have placed all html elements and now I need code implementation. My question is: "How to code html elements to achieve desired functionality?".

Tried to follow up through this solution to add code behind masterpage: http://rburgundy.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/sharepoint-2010-custom-masterpage-with-code-behind-file-%E2%80%93-part-2/
but I get an error which I don't know how to handle.
Here is the error:

> Parser Error Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately. Parser Error Message: Could not load the assembly
>   'Branding102, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=84d1d0117dd4046d'. Make sure that it is compiled before
>   accessing the page. 
>   Source Error: Line 1:

I need to implement `_starter.cs` file as code-behind masterpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with webparts in your master page.

Delegate control is your friend.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650763.aspx

http://fyeomans.com/2011/05/16/make-your-sharepoint-2010-master-page-extensible-with-delegate-controls/

You can write your delegate control to be full postback or Ajax, implementation is up to you.

Personally, having webparts in masterpage is a no-no for me, that's what page layouts are for. In masterpage, delegate control is THE prefered method to have custom html/code rendering.

Comment: Finaly I managed to focus on my SharePoint problem. You were right, delegate control was my friend and it will be from now on. Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

http://edwin.vriethoff.net/2007/10/02/how-to-send-an-e-mail-with-attachment-from-sharepoint/

Something like this within a web part and then add a web part to your master page.

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't want users to bother with webparts. I have bunch of sites and enabling webparts on each site is not the solution. And I want Suggestions form to be placed in header area beside SP username.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can install the web part at root level, add it to the master page. This should then distribute across all site using this master page. Essentially you add the web part only once and the user has no option but to accept that it is there